# How to divide many connected circles into single in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I already processed the original image to binary image. Here it is.
[image]

And this is the binary image,after the processing.
[image]

This is my source code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("keli.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("org",img)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,200,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)
ret1, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(thresh,40,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh1)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And now I am trying to detect all the circles in this image,but there is a problem,I can't divide them in to single circle.I already tried to use edge detect,erode and dilate to process this image,but the effect is not good enough.
So,Is there any good method to solve this problem.

Comment: did you try edge detection on the original image? Maybe don't use canny but try gradient extraction to get some feeling for the image data.

Comment: I already try to detect the circles by using sobel edge,but  I think that is not enough to detect all the circles accurately.

Comment: How are you counting the circles obscured by the edge?  (leave them off?)

Comment: do you know or can you determine the approximate average circle size without detecting all the circles? (it looks like all the circles have similar size, so there won't be any real circles that are much bigger/smaller than those ones?)

Comment: if you know the approximate average circle size, you might be able to look closer to the image/mask. since your mask is good, you'll know that there are still circles missing if you have areas in your binary mask that are masked but not covered by a circle.

Comment: Any luck with edge boosting with some high pass filter before edge detection?

Comment: I do not like the binary image ... why not try to extract dark colors from your original image ... that should preserve the circular like boundary much closer. Now you have boundaries and background color merged together making the circle detection much harder I think